# What's the best way to combine systemic functional grammar and historical linguistics?

Tags: historical-linguistics, systemic-functional, interdisciplinary

What's the best way to combine SFL/SFG and historical linguistics? I've just thought of diachronic genre analysis as being an interesting area to explore, but my understanding is that that's got more to do with pragmatics.